# Autoprefixer error on Sublime Text 2

Tags: css, node.js, sublimetext2, autoprefixer

I'm trying to install Autoprefixer for Sublime Text 2 and I'm getting the following error:

> Autoprefixer   Error:    /Users/labedzde/Library/Application
>   Support/Sublime Text
>   2/Packages/Autoprefixer/node_modules/get-stdin/index.js:7     return
>   new Promise(function (resolve) {
>                ^   ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
>       at module.exports (/Users/labedzde/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   2/Packages/Autoprefixer/node_modules/get-stdin/index.js:7:13)
>       at Object. (/Users/labedzde/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Autoprefixer/autoprefixer.js:7:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:906:3

I have node.js already installed and it's version 0.10.32.

What does the error mean and how can I install Autoprefixer?

Comment: to be honest most people don't use autoprefixer as part of IDE's, they implement it as part of a build process. Have you looked into gulp?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your nodejs version, please see this note from the [GH page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer):
You need to have **Node.js >=0.12.0** installed.